# Virtual Machine Information

Tags: linux

i'm currently using windows 7 64 bit on a lenovo laptop and i have installed linux kali 2.0 on vmware. So the basic question is if i'm doing any attack on others network or any kind of testing through my ethernet connecton doess it possible that there is any option they can track me down.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is. Depending on the attack, it may be entirely trivial. Kali Linux is designed for ethical hacking, for penetration testing of networks you control. It is not designed to be used immorally and is most certainly not designed to launch attacks that are impossible to track.

Many or most of the penetration tests launchable from Kali Linux can easily be traced back to the point of origin.